# The output in my terminal is followed by strange characters

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 
}
```

When running this my terminal outputs the following:

```
cd "/Users//Desktop/C:C++/" && g++ main2.cpp -o main2 && "/Users//Desktop/C:C++/"main2

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
3c0630455fab:C:C++ $ cd "/Users//Desktop/C:C++/" && g++ main2.cpp -o main2 && "/Users//Desktop/C:C++/"main2
Hello World!3c0630455fab:C:C++ $
```

What are these strange characters following the output?

Comment: Add new line `"Hello World!\n"`

Comment: For me it works without strange characters at the end. Please correct: "return 0;" (add return value and semicolon). (BTW, do not use special characters like "+" and ":" in file or directory names.)

Comment: @273K yes, it looks like this is just the normal prompt :)

Comment: I bet it actually complains about a missing semicolon after `return`.  (This is why we cut and paste instead of re-typing.)

Answer (score 2):

It is showing those weird characters because you never added a new line after `"Hello World!"`. It is printing your string, but since you didn't tell it to go to the next line, your terminal input is starting right after `World!`.

That is why `3c0630455fab:C:C++ rbrangri$`, your terminal name/path, is printed directly after your string!

To fix this, you can append a `\n` inside of your string, or add a endline like this:  `<< std::endl;`